# Python and PHP not returning the same results for a similiarly seeded RNG

Tags: php, python

I currently need to use a script that requires python and PHP to output the same random numbers given a seed. Is there any RNG that can let them do this?

When I use mt_rand and mt_srand and python's default rng (which is supposed to be mersenne twist) with the same seed I get different results.

Comment: You can always write your own. There are many simple formulas for that.

Comment: I am currently looking for a library to do this as I will 99.9% screw up an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no requirement than Python and PHP (or any other language) should generate the same random number for the same seed.